# Reactive Loading state management with RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

A classic task when you have some input field and you have to fetch something on values changes. Let's imagine we use Angular Reactive Forms. Example:

```
orders$ = inputControl.valueChanges.pipe(
   switchMap((value) => {
     return someService.fetch(value);
   })
);
```

Now we should also somehow manage loading state. I usually use `tap`:

```
orders$ = inputControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  tap(() => { loading = true }), // or loading$.next(true) if loading is a subject
  switchMap((value) => {
    return someService.fetch(value);
  }),
  tap(() => { loading = false }), // or loading$.next(false) if loading is a subject
);
```

However it seems we can somehow avoid assigning values in the `tap` and use RxJs instead.
But I could not find a way to do with it.

For me, the usage of the ideal solution would be

```
orders$ = <some abstraction here that depends on inputControl.valueChanges and fetching>
loading$ = <some abstraction here that depends on fetching>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about the loading state as part of a larger "order search request", then it becomes easier to see how to use RxJS to create an observable that emits the desired overall state.

Instead of having two separate observables, `orders$` and `loading$`, you could have a single observable that emits both pieces of data (*since they are always changed at the same time*).

We basically want to create an observable that initially emits:

```json
{ 
    isLoading: true, 
    results: undefined
}
```

then, after the results are received, emits:

```json
{ 
    isLoading: false, 
    results: ** orders from api call ** 
}
```

We can achieve by using [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap), [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map), and [`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith):

```js
  orderSearchRequest$ = this.searchTerm$.pipe(
    switchMap(term => this.searchService.search(term).pipe(
      map(results => ({ isLoading: false, results })),
      startWith({ isLoading: true, results: undefined })
    )),
  );
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="searchTerm" placeholder="Order Search">
</form>

<div *ngIf="orderSearchRequest$ | async as request">

  <div *ngIf="request.isLoading"> loading... </div>

  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let order of request.results">
      {{ order.description }}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75202533?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.

Comment: Simple solution, but what happens when the search() action throws an error? It get stucks in the loading state, right? It misses the catchError(error => {

    return of({ loading: false, results: [] });
})

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my library ez-state.

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez/tree/master/projects/ez-state

https://adrianbrand.medium.com/angular-state-management-using-services-built-with-ez-state-9b23f16fb5ae

```
orderCache = new EzCache<Order[]>();

order$ = this.orderCache.value$;

loading$ = this.orderCache.loading$;

inputControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  orderCache.load(someService.fetch(value));
});
```

An EzCache is a glorified behaviour subject that has methods load, save, update and delete and manages state observables like loading$, loaded$, saving$, saved$ etc.

I would personally would have the cache in the service and expose the observables from the service like in that article I wrote.

Comment: This made me add a poll method to the cache, I have been meaning to do this for a while. Now the subscription to the inputControl can be replaced with orderCache.poll(inputControl.valueChanges.pipe(map(value => someService.fetch(value)))). Poll takes an observable that emits an observable of the type of the cache. The code is on GitHub but I cannot push to npm from here, will update npm when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RxJS `scan` operator to keep track of the loading state without introducing side-effects.

```js
// The interface for our loading state
interface LoadingState<T = unknown> {
  loading: boolean;
  error?: Error | null;
  data?: T;
}

// Using scan to manage our loading state
orders$ = this.inputControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMap((value) =>
      this.someService.fetch(value).pipe(
        // We transform data and mark as not loading
        map((data) => ({ data, loading: false })),
        // In case of error, we catch it and mark as not loading
        catchError((error) => of({ error, loading: false })),
        // We emit an initial loading state
        startWith({ error: null, loading: true })
      )
    ),
    // scan accumulates changes and emits the current state
    scan((state: LoadingState<Order>, change: LoadingState<Order>) => ({ 
      ...state, 
      ...change,
    }))
  );
```

If you are going to be using this pattern in multiple places in your application, you may want to create your own reusable RxJS operator.

For example:

```js
// switch-map-with-loading.ts
export function switchMapWithLoading<T>(
  observableFunction: (value: any) => Observable<T>
): OperatorFunction<any, LoadingState<T>> {
  return (source: Observable<any>) =>
    source.pipe(
      switchMap((value) =>
        observableFunction(value).pipe(
          map((data) => ({ data, loading: false })),
          catchError((error) => of({ error, loading: false })),
          startWith({ error: null, loading: true })
        )
      ),
      scan((state: LoadingState<T>, change: LoadingState<T>) => ({
        ...state,
        ...change,
      }))
    );
}
```

You can then import the operator in your component and use it like this:

```js
orders$ = this.inputControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMapWithLoading<Order>((value) => this.someService.fetch(value))
);
```

Comment: I created a structural directive called [ngx-load-with](https://github.com/rensjaspers/ngx-load-with) that makes it even easier to track loading states and [load stuff based on other data](https://github.com/rensjaspers/ngx-load-with#loading-based-on-changes-to-other-data). It uses the above trick under the hood with some optimizations and extras.

Comment: This solution looks good, however why do we need `scan` operator here? It seems if we have data returned from `map`, it returns necessary object, as well as `catchError` and `startWith`.

Comment: Without the `scan` operator we'd lose the previously loaded data as soon as we start reloading. While not always necessary, I often find it to be a better user experience when I can keep displaying old data while new data is being loaded.